# stackPanel expanding?

Tags: java, gwt, stackpanel

I have a normal stackpanel like http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackLayoutPanel

but no i dont want, that my other widget collapse when i expand an other one.

like in smartgwt :

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_sections_expand_collapse

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution that meets all your needs. I have recently looked into this exact same issue in depth and these are the options I came up with.

### Write/Modify your own component

You can try extending StackLayoutPanel to add the functionality you require. The animate method is public in the latest version (it's not in 2.0) but you would have to add a bit of tweaking to keep track of which panels are expanded. It may be easier to simply use it as a base for a new widget. Source code [here](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/release/2.6/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackLayoutPanel.java).

**Pros:** Can guarantee exact functionality and modify it on demand.

**Cons:** Requires in depth knowledge and development time.

### DisclosurePanels stacked in a VerticalPanel

This is the closest GWT has to offer if you need to use standard widgets. DisclosurePanels allow you to have a header widget that, when clicked, expands or hides the content widget. With multiple stacked on top of each other you can have multiple opened at once.

Disclosure panels will not resize their content to fit a constrained space however. If they are too big for the space provided they will push further DisclosurePanels out of view. This is fine if you don't mind having to scroll to see other headers.

**Pros:** Uses standard GWT components and easy to implement.

**Cons:** Not all headers may be visible at the same time depending on the length of the content of expanded sections.

### Use StackLayoutPanel

**Pros:** Uses standard GWT components and easy to implement. All headers visible at all times.

**Cons:** Only one section visible at a time.

### Use a third-party component

SmartGWT springs to mind. ;)

**Pros:** You may be able to get the exact functionality you are after.

**Cons:** Have to use a third-party component that may be buggy or add other unnecessary bloat to your code.